# How do I stop multiple images in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, image

I want to stop generating multiple images in wordPress.

I tried to set height & width to 0 in settings>media.
Secondly, there is no option of images size in function.php (in my wordpress theme).

Please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a filter built in to modify this behavior, just add this function to your functions.php file

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced',' prefix_remove_default_images');
// This will remove the default image sizes and the medium_large size. 
function prefix_remove_default_images( $sizes ) {
     unset($sizes['small']);
     unset($sizes['medium']);
     unset($sizes['large']);
     unset($sizes['medium_large']);
     return $sizes;
}
```